# Swing delegating drop event to parent container

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, droptarget

I want to delegate a "drop" event of a `JList` to its parent (`JPanel`) and remove the visual feedback of dropping on JList.

What is the correct way to do this?

I am trying to create a `DropTarget` object and share it between the JPanel and JList, but it seems a bit hackish --- I can't figure out what `DropTarget.getComponent()` supposed to do and worry it may break stuff.

Can you advice the correct way to do this (in Java 6)?

**EDIT:**
**Why I am doing this?**

I am trying to let the user to put items into groups (one JPanel + one JList = one group) --the list order will not be preserved (and cannot be preserved because of some internal data-structures) when the item is dropped on the `JList`.

The default visual feedback for `JList` is a line-like cursor hinting where it will be added. If I use the default, the user will be confused when he found the item is added to the end of list, not where the cursor have shown.

To make the visual feedback look easier, I am doing it on JPanel-level (one JPanel for one JList, some semi-transparent overlay over the list and stuff..). Naturally, dropping to that JPanel should add to the list as well. So....

Comment: *"What is the correct way to do this?"*  Umm.. **Don't** do it because it is not 'the path of least surprise' for the end user?

Comment: @AndrewThompson In fact, I am doing this make it less surprise. see the updated question.

Comment: don't think it's surprising, it's what f.i. win file explorer does: drag a directory from the tree to a list view of the files of another directory, when over a file, a black line indicating current insertion position is shown, but on drop the dir is inserted according to the sort order

Comment: I agree with @kleopatra . I think the typical file browser keeps the inserted file selected by default to visualize show the user where it it placed, since the actual location differs from the drop location. Good thing too or none of my folders would have files in alphabetical order and I would never find anything back

Comment: @kleopatra, have you tried it in winxp? Here explorer does not show the "black line", and it never insert to the sort order -- it just add it to the end of list.

Comment: @Robin, try this case in winxp: Create two folder (`A`, `B`). Create a folder `C` in `A`. Open a command prompt, `cd A\C`. Try to move `A` into `B`. -- Result: a error is shown (expected), a folder `A` is created in `B`, but it is not highlighted.  : Hilights lost when the dialog is shown. Is this good user experience? Never mention there are lots of other way losting focus.

Comment: no, I'm on vista here - so it's not surprising for me, but might for xp users. But don't understand you comment to @Robin - "command line"? What's that ... aren't we talking about guis ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra, that command prompt is for "locking" the folder -- make it unmovable and make it prompt the error when you move it.

Answer (score 1):

The visual feedback for the drop location is handled by the cell renderer. A dirty trick to remove is a custom renderer which does nothing in that respect (note that the logic is not complete, you'll probably have to handle the "real" selection case):

```
    ListCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
                    cellHasFocus);
            JList.DropLocation dropLocation = list.getDropLocation();
            if (dropLocation != null
                    && !dropLocation.isInsert()
                    && dropLocation.getIndex() == index) {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
                setForeground(list.getForeground());
            }
            return this;
        }

    };
```

That combined with a custom transferHandler which is installed both on the list and the containing panel should be very near to what you need (in its importData, add the item to the end of the list, select the new entry and scroll to it)

Comment: You are working on JList... Is there any ways to delegate the drop to parent JPanel?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to preserve the JList drag&drop handling, the easiest way to achieve this is to set its TransferHandler to null. Assuming that its parent has a TransferHandler set, it will then automatically get to handle drag&drop events.

Comment: cool - my learn item of the day, and exactly what the OP is looking for :-)